# fabirc js with react : how can i control line when i move circle?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

[image]

When i drag and move red or blue circle, the length and angle of the line changes.
In other words, Both ends of the line must always lie in the center of the circle.

but in my code, the line is fixed.
How to solve this problem?
Group is required?
Is it efficient to include line in both group((circle1,line),(circle2,line))?
[image]

This is my code.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement|null>(null);
    let circle1:fabric.Circle;
    let circle2:fabric.Circle;
    let line:fabric.Line;

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current as HTMLCanvasElement);

        
        circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            radius: 50,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            selectable: true,

        });

        circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
            left: 250,
            top: 250,
            radius: 50,
            fill: 'blue',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            selectable: true,
        });

        
        line = new fabric.Line([circle1.left + 50, circle1.top + 50, circle2.left + 50, circle2.top + 50], {
            stroke: 'green',
            strokeWidth: 3,
            selectable: false,
        });

        
        
        
        canvas.add(circle1,circle2,line);
        

        
        circle1.on('moving', () => {
            if (circle1 && line) {
                line.set({
                    x1: circle1.left,
                    y1: circle1.top,
                });
                canvas.renderAll();
            }

        });

        circle2.on('moving', () => {
            if (circle2 && line) {
                line.set({
                    x2: circle2.left,
                    y2: circle2.top,
                });
                canvas.renderAll();
            }
        });

        
        canvas.renderAll();
    }, []);

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={1000} height={700} />;
};
```